# How can I make my sim harvest the whole garden automatically again?

Tags: the-sims-3

When you're harvesting your garden, usually if you click "harvest" or "tend garden", the Sim will go around and perform these actions to every plant in the garden that the action is applicable to.

My Sim was doing this just fine until I moved neighbourhoods. I used the "copy to library" feature to move my Sims into a new neighbourhood, and since this, my Sim will not tend multiple plants automatically. I have to issue an instruction for each and every plant.

The exact behaviour is like this:

- If I "Tend Garden" on a plant that is not ready for harvest, the Sim will tend that plant and all other plants that are not ready for harvest (by watering/weeding).
- If I "Tend Garden" on a plant that is ready for harvest, the action is immediately cancelled, with no thought bubble above my Sim
- If I "Harvest" on a harvestable plant, my Sim will harvest that plant
- If I queue up multiple "Harvest" actions, my Sim will cancel all Harvest actions after the first
- After a plant has been harvested once, it never becomes harvestable again

Is my save file just bugged now? Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried planting new plants (since you copied the files)? Or removing and replanting the existing ones? If so, do they exhibit the same behaviour?

Comment: It could be a bug: http://forum.thesims3.com/jforum/posts/list/582523.page  if so this mod might help you: http://www.modthesims.info/showthread.php?t=486383

Comment: I would like to help, but I'm stuck in an endless panic mode trying to even create my sims...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove all the plants and start your garden again. You must plant everything again since it was a copy. Sometimes stuff goes wrong when you are copying a house. You can also try moving to another house and try planting a garden there if my first suggestion doesn't work